# Java hibernate delete fails due to update entity not null constraint

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, orm

I have the following hibernate structure:

A decision has by definition some parameters that define the possible inputs and outputs. A decision also has one or more rules and each rule has some decision rule input parameters and output parameters that are linked to the decision parameters:

```
public class Decision {

   @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
   private String name;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "decision", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   private List<DecisionParameter> parameters = new ArrayList<>();

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "decision", orphanRemoval = true)
   private List<DecisionRule> rules = new ArrayList<>();

}

public class DecisionParameter {

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "decision_id", table = "decision_parameter", nullable = false,
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_decision_parameter_decision_id"))
   private Decision decision;

}

public class DecisionRule {

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "decisionRule", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   @Where(clause = "type = 1")
   private List<DecisionRuleParameter> inputs = new ArrayList<>();

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "decisionRule", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   @Where(clause = "type = 2")
   private List<DecisionRuleParameter> outputs = new ArrayList<>();

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "decision_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_decision_item_decision_id"))
   private Decision decision;

}

public class DecisionRuleParameter {

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "decision_parameter_id", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_decision_paramater_decision_parameter_id"))
   private DecisionParameter decisionParameter;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "decision_rule_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_decision_rule_decision_rule_id"))
   private DecisionRule decisionRule;

}

@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class DecisionRuleInputParameter extends DecisionRuleParameter {
   ...
}

@DiscriminatorValue("2")
public class DecisionRuleOutputParameter extends DecisionRuleParameter {
   ...
}
```

When I try to delete a `decision` object:

hibernate updates the decision rule parameters by setting the decision_parameter_id to null

```
update model.decision_rule_parameter set decision_parameter_id = NULL where id = ...
```

tiggering a not null constraint:

```
ERROR: null value in column "decision_parameter_id" of relation "decision_rule_parameter" violates not-null constraint
```

Why does this happen and how can I make sure that hibernates does not set the id to null? I do not want to remove the not null constraint.